# Azure sphere error 'id returned 1 exit status'

Tags: c, azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-sphere

I'm working on azure sphere, I did only two examples till now and I'm new two C, and this error(id returned 1 exit status) was not there previously, But now in every project other than blinking light(Azure Sphere demo project) I'm getting it.

I tried everything like restart my system reboot the azure sphere and ven reinstalled visual studio and azure sphere sdk. still facing the same issue.

Desperately looking for one answer other than restart my system.
I expect the output to be anything other than this error:id returned 1 exit status.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a sample that you can share? Or more info about the error you see, or a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

That error is an undefined reference to your main function 
Make sure you have your: int main(void) function {}
At the very beginning and all your codes are inside the curly brackets '{}' 
Hope this helps